# Casting Syntax to Loop Through Array of Arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, loops

I have an `NSArray` consisting of `NSArrays` of strings created in Objective-C.

I now want to loop through the items in the array in a swift class and am having trouble with the syntax.

The original Objective-C Array of arrays looks like the following:

```
NSArray* shapes =@[@[@"square",@"square.png"],@[@"circle",@"circle.png"],@[@"square",@"square.png"]];
```

I am able to get and print the Array from the Objective-C class using:

```
let shapes:Array = Utilities.sharedInstance().getShapes
```

The following to loop through the array, however, is not compiling:

```
var term : String = ""
var pic : String = ""
for shape in shapes  {
term  = shape[1] //ERROR HERE
pic = shape[2] //SAME ERROR HERE
            }
```

It gives the error:  `Type 'Any' has no subscript members`

What is the proper syntax to loop through the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 let shapes = Utilities.sharedInstance().getShapes as! [[String]]
```

Your `Array` elements are of type `Any` so you can't use [] with them until you cast , it's always the case when you use bridged code from objective-c , so you have to be specific about the actual type you use , also i encourage

```
struct Item {
   let term,pic:String
}
```

Then

```
let res:[Item] = shapes.map { Item(term:$0[0],pic:$0[1]) }
```

an irrelevant note but important you can do

```
NSArray* shapes = @[@"square",@"circle",@"square"];
```

then the matter of appending .png is simple instead of having an `[[String]]` directly it's `[String]`

Comment: This is a sidenote, but apparently the first element of an array in swift is [1] as opposed to [0]?

Comment: swift array indexing is zer0-based also , for your case you can easily test it with `shape[2]` and it will crash the app with index-out of range exception

Comment: OK.  That makes more sense.